# Passing props through in ReactJS and they won't load, while receiving a target container error?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, state, prop

hopefully someone can shed some light on the recent issues I've been running into. I'm attempting to make a landing page for someone to edit some profile information (username, email, etc.). The problem is when I pass the props from one function to another, they load as undefined. The relevant code is below...

```
class ChangeFields extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: [
                {
                    username: "test"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    render() {
        const formSample = (
            <div>
                <h3>Account Information:</h3>
                <br></br>
                <CurrentInfo user={this.state.user} onItemSelect={this.updateInfo()} />
            </div>
        );
        return formSample;
    }
}

const CurrentInfo = ({user, onItemSelect}) => {
    console.log(user.username);
    const formElement = (
        <Form horizontal>
            <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalUsername">
                <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                    {user.username}
                </Col>
                <Col sm={10} value={user.username}>
                    <FormControl controlId="testControl" value={user.username} />
                </Col>
            </FormGroup>
        </Form>
    );
    return formElement;
};
```

Unfortunately, the "user.username" in the CurrentInfo block outputs as undefined. Any insight? Note: this is a simplified version of the code, if more is needed I can provide it.

It is also worth noting, that I receive a warning of: Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

I have attempted to move my  line in index.html to the bottom, as others have suggested but that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Its qn array of user. Map through it or select the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, the "user.username" in the CurrentInfo block outputs as undefined. Any insight?

This:

```
this.state = {
            user: [
                {
                    username: "test"
                }
            ]
        }
```

should be:

```
this.state = {user: {username: "test"}};
```

You're currently setting the `user` property to an array.

> It is also worth noting, that I receive a warning of: Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

This is probably happening in code that is not in your question.

Comment: Thanks so much, can't believe that was it. I was following a format where someone uploaded it to a table, with mapping, so I guess that's why it worked for the table and not form. Thanks again!

Comment: @semcmill Happy to help. Don't forget to hit the checkmark next to this answer so others know this question is answered+complete.